# How to use dataTables in Angular2

Tags: html, typescript, angular, datatable, datepicker

I am searching for a way to make my table sortable by clicking on the column names but I cannot figure it out. I tried different ways that I found on the internet like installing  angular2-datable (npm install angular-data-table) and do an import {DataTableDirectives} from 'angular2-datatable/datatable'; installing easytable (npm install ng2-easy-table) but it didn't work for me. I am also looking for a datepicker that works on all the browsers but couldn't find anyone.

Do you guys have any suggestions? I am working with Typescript and Angular2.

Please help!!

Comment: You can use it with Angular 2. I am currently using its basic functionalities with Angular 2 such as paging, search etc.. Let me know if you're still looking for an answer.

Comment: If anyone ends up in this question, there is a npm package (although dataTables just depends on jQuery, so you should be able to use it if you configure angular 2 to use jquery). https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable

Answer (score 2):

The best way to use prime ng grid  .That makes Better Ui

http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/

Comment: Try to answer the question instead of telling him not to use this library.

Comment: Although I agree with this answer, this is not answering at all the question

Answer (score 0):

I am also unable to install angular-datatable because of permission denied while accessing **.config** directory.
You can add using the following command:
**sudo chown -R : /path/to/home/directory/.config**

This will transfer ownership to **user_name** .Let me know,if you find other error.